# Hidden modal div still present after close

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having quite a big issue with closing modals and Twitter Bootstrap. I'll try as best as I can to explain.

I have a modal which I can open and close, and that works well. Except for the fact that when I close the modal, the div still seems to be present (but it's hidden), hovering over the nav bar, which is painful because it sits above the navbar and none of the links can be clicked. The bug seems to be limited to Safari and Chrome (it doesn't happen in Firefox).

I've attached two images to help illustrate the problem further [[first](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dh0d6z1vsp55843/navbarissue_1.png), [second](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nqnvbqxcdq2rn9u/navbarissue_2.45%20AM%20copy.png)]. The first is showing the entirety of the div present over the navbar after I've closed the modal, and the second is showing that the problem seems to lie with the modal footer.

I can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong and I haven't been able to find any bug reports in bootstrap relating to it.

EDIT: Included some HTML

```
<div id="IMS_modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <h3 id="IMS_modalHeader">
            Editing Data
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" id="IMS_editform">
            <div class="control-group" style="display:none;">
                <label class="control-label">ID</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="IMS_ID">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group" id="IMS_servername_control">
                <label class="control-label">Server Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="IMS_servername"> &nbsp;<a href="#" rel="tooltip" id="IMS_servername_tooltip" title="Please provide a valid server name"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group" id="IMS_nodeid_control">
                <label class="control-label">Node ID</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="IMS_nodeid" maxlength="8"> &nbsp;<a href="#" rel="tooltip" id="IMS_nodeid_tooltip" title="Please provide a valid node ID"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group" id="IMS_ipaddress_control">
                <label class="control-label">IP Address</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="IMS_ipaddress"> &nbsp;<a href="#" rel="tooltip" class="validate" id="IMS_ipaddress_tooltip" title="Please provide a valid IP Address"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="control-group" id="IMS_activeims_control">
                    <label class="control-label">Port</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" maxlength="4" id="IMS_port"> &nbsp;<a href="#" rel="tooltip" id="IMS_port_tooltip" title="Please provide a valid active state"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br/>
            <div class="control-group" id="IMS_activeims_control">
                <label class="control-label">Active IMS</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input id="IMS_activeims" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="true"><br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group" id="IMS_activeims_control">
                <label class="control-label">Monitor Connections</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input id="IMS_monitor" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="true"><br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="saveIMSEdit()">Save changes &nbsp;</button> <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Need to see some HTML at least to help out

Comment: Close your <form> before you close <div class=modal-body>

Comment: I see you made an edit. Now there's one </div> too much

Comment: Sorry, should be correct now. Made an error in copying. Problem still occurs.

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: i concur with @reinder.. it's kind of hard to debug at it's current state (too little info).. can you isolate your problem and upload it to github or somewhere where we can test the code ourselves?

Comment: the only way i could replicate your problem if i deselect the display:none property of .hide in <div id="IMS_modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1">, which is the parent div of the modal view.. if i did that.. then i couldn't click on any of the links.. but then again that was the same behaviour in firefox.. so i doubt if that's your problem.. so yeah please give us some code that we can run on a browser and see what problem u're facing